# javascript access a json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

this might sound dumb but I am trying to display the value of content:
I do `console.log(teams);`
I open firebug on mozilla and here is what I get :

```
 [Object { id= "50",  content= "Team 1 test" ,  date="Tue Mar 26 2013 12:00:00"}]
```

when I do `alert(teams.content);` or `alert(teams[content]);`
it returns object undefined.What am I doing wrong please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object is wrapped in an array (notice the `[` and `]`)

```
teams[0].content;
```

Comment: console.log(teams[0]); this returns : Object { id=

"50"

, content=

"Team Pro-Motion test"

, date=

"Tue Mar 26 2013 12:00:00"

}

Comment: but if I add the .content, it says undefined again

Comment: @fogsy add `.content` to what?

Comment: to teams[0] ... so when I do console.log(teams[0].content); its undefined.

Comment: @fogsy can you show us an example on jsfiddle.net or your actual site?

Comment: huge code and its on local server. I marked up all the answers they were all good I Will try to figure it out and post an answer on here. thanks Explosion

Comment: I fixed it, its because it was inside a loop and the first value had no results so it was returning an error and breaking the loop

Comment: var eventsOfDay        = getEventsOfDay(options, dayNumber);
   var eme = eventsOfDay[0];
   
      if (eventsOfDay && eventsOfDay.length != 0) {
    console.log(eme.content);   }

Answer (score 3):

Its not just object, but an array of objects, .
Your object is at `0th` index of array.

So try this,

```
alert(teams[0].content)
```

Also,  `alert(teams[content]);` is a wrong way. The index should be a string here.

So, another way would be,

```
alert(teams[0]['content']);
```

Comment: TypeError: eventsOfDay[0] is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

console.log(eventsOfDay[0]['content']);

Comment: you said teams. not eventsOfDay!

Comment: yes but its the same. just the variable name that is different.

Comment: @fogsy, I guess you can remove your comments now as you have find out that error is caused by something else.

Answer (score 1):

Teams is an array.

To read a value you need to index it

```
teams[index].content
```

Comment: on here it asys index is not defined.

Comment: I didnt mean to say use index per se.. but a variable that indexes into the array.. for example if var size = teams.length; now you can use teams[x].content to access the xth element of the array. where 0<= x < size